# How to check if a text input string on change has an Uppercase letter Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check if a text input, on change, has an uppercase letter, in the string using just javascript (or in combination with regex)?

*For example:*

```
const passwordInput = document.querySelector("#password");
passwordInput.addEventListener("change", e => {
    if (e.target.value does not contain an uppercase letter) {
        console.log("Must contain an uppercase letter.")
    }
})
```

Comment: in what Unicode range?

Comment: `/[A-Z]/.test(e.target.value)`

Comment: @CRice Ž is not uppercase?

Comment: @Roko Do you use unicode characters in your passwords? You're a bold man.

Comment: @CRice yes, I use symbols and emojis just to blame BE developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (e.target.value == e.target.value.toLowerCase()) { }
```